# Got this error after installing node; Cannot find module 'yallist' Require stack........Will appreciate response on comment box

Tags: reactjs, nodes

node -v  brought out the version,whereas npm -v displays error.

npm -v
internal/module/cjs/loader:933
const err= new Error(message);

cannot find module 'yallist'
Require stack:
c/users/david/AppData/roaming/npm/node_module/Iru cache/index.js
c/users/david/AppData/roaming/npm/node_module/server/classes/range.js

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall nodejs, clean your node_modules.

Reinstall nodejs and npm and try again.

Let us know if that fix the issue

Comment: I keep having the same issue, after reinstalling

Comment: i fianlly got it working now. I cleared off d node module, uninstalled it for a latest version, added a path under environmental variable.

Comment: Great, you can add an answer explaining what you have done exactly for future users.